# Wait for response before returning

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux

For an app I'm working on, we're using server side React rendering with Redux stores and we need to communicate with our API. This all works pretty well, but for some views I need the data *before* I render it to the browser. I'm using [react-fetcher](https://github.com/markdalgleish/react-fetcher) to execute a function before rendering and with static test data this works perfectly fine. But as soon as I want to use data from the API, I'm lost. Everything is async but that means that my app renders before I've a result back from my API.

My code looks like this:

```
function getData(apiToken, dispatch) {
  superagent.get('http://api.url/endpoint')
    .set('x-api-token', apiToken)
    .end((err, res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'MY_STORE_ACTION',
        data: res.body
      });
  });
}


@prefetch(({ dispatch, apiToken }) => getData(apiToken, dispatch))
```

Of course, this won't work because `end` is an async callback and my app isn't waiting for it.

It's probably worth mentioning that I'm pretty new to the world of ECMAScript and NodeJS (coming from PHP) so perhaps my way of thinking is just plain wrong ;-)

Comment: Always prepare components so that if your props are empty `{}` or `null` it won't crash. Even if you fetch data before rendering on the server when your app loads and you navigate between routes there will still be asynchronous data loading going on. I have never used `react-fetcher`, but I would suggest trying to render your component inside of the `end()` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `react-fetcher` docs you are supposed to call dispatch using your `getData` function.

I would try the following:

```
function getData(apiToken) {
  // prefetch expects you to return a promise
  return superagent.get('http://api.url/endpoint')
    .set('x-api-token', apiToken)
    .end((err, res) => {
      return {
        type: 'MY_STORE_ACTION',
        data: res.body
      };
  });
}

@prefetch(({ dispatch, apiToken }) => dispatch(getData(apiToken))
```

And make sure you return your promise as noted above. According to the docs:

> The `@prefetch` decorator is for universal data, while `@defer` is for data that is only required on the client. They each accept a function that **returns a promise**.